# How to address data in a hierarchical data structure in R?

Tags: list, r, data-structures

I created a list containing two data lists (character array `region` and a list `results`) of the same length. (I tried to manage the data in data.frame, but it seems to be complicated to add data to a data.frame).

```
study = list(
    region  = character(),
    results = list()
)

study$region[1] = "Hamburg"
study$results[[1]]  = data.frame(month=c(1:5), maxTemp=c(-12, -1, 3, 10, 23))


study$region[2]    = "Bremen"
study$results[[2]]  = data.frame(month=c(1:5), maxTemp=c(-9, -1, 6, 10, 21))

str(study)

print("Maximum temperature of all study regions:")
max(study$results[[1:2]]$maxTemp)
```

I want to find out the maximum temperature of all timepoint of all regions. I can address each region after another by using e.g. `max(study$results[[1]]$maxTemp`, but when I try to address all regions `max(study$results[[1:2]]$maxTemp` I receive an error:

> Error in study$results[[1:2]]$maxTemp :
>
> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Where is my mistake? How can I address fields of a several `data.frame`s that are saved in a `list` of a `list`? And what are atomic vectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[` can only return a single element. I thought `[[` would have thrown an error because of that, not the error you are seeing, but reading `?"["` tells what R does with a call such as yours and explains the behaviour (from `?"["`):

> Recursive (list-like) objects:
>   ....
>
> ```
>  ‘[[’ can be applied recursively to lists, so that if the single
>  index ‘i’ is a vector of length ‘p’, ‘alist[[i]]’ is equivalent to
>  ‘alist[[i1]]...[[ip]]’ providing all but the final indexing
>  results in a list.
> ```

The reason for your error is this:

```
> study$results[[c(1,2)]]
[1] -12  -1   3  10  23
```

which indicates that R really did this

```
> study$results[[1]][[2]]
[1] -12  -1   3  10  23
```

i.e. return the second component (column) of the first data frame, which is an atomic vector because R drops the empty dimension. `$` can not be used on atomic vectors hence the error.

If you want to iterate over the list that is `study$results`, `lapply()` or `sapply()` are your friends:

```
> lapply(study$results, function(y) max(y[, "maxTemp"], na.rm = TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] 23

[[2]]
[1] 21

> sapply(study$results, function(y) max(y[, "maxTemp"], na.rm = TRUE))
[1] 23 21
```

If you popped names on the components in `$results` you'd get them in the output too:

```
> names(study$results) <- study$region
> lapply(study$results, function(y) max(y[, "maxTemp"], na.rm = TRUE))
$Hamburg
[1] 23

$Bremen
[1] 21

> sapply(study$results, function(y) max(y[, "maxTemp"], na.rm = TRUE))
Hamburg  Bremen 
     23      21
```

which is easier to use and then you don't need the `$region` component if you wish.

Comment: Worked fine. I had to address the column "maxTemp" using `y[["maxTemp"]]`

Comment: Is there some specific reason to use `y[, ...]` instead of `y[...]`? What is the comma for?

Comment: @Sven That is another way to get the `maxTemp` component. Use whichever you feel is easiest etc.

Comment: @hhh no specific reason, I just grew up thinking of a data frame as an array-matrix-like object rather than a list, so the `y[i, j]` notation means ith row of jth column (as `i` was missing in my example, it means give all rows). Your notation treats the data frame as a list and indexes that way. Note there is a difference however; `[, "maxTemp"]` and `[["maxTemp"]]` return a numeric vector whereas `["maxTemp"]` returns a data frame with one column/component. This is all simplified over inside the `lapply` call but is worth remembering.

Answer (score 4):

You are way overcomplicating things with your data structure.  You want a single data frame with three columns: `month`, `maxTemp` and `region`.

```
n_months <- 5
(study <- data.frame(
  month   = rep.int(1:n_months, 2),
  maxTemp = c(12, -1, 3, 10, 23, -9, -1, 6, 10, 21),
  region  = rep(c("Hamburg", "Bremen"), each = n_months)
))

   month maxTemp  region
1      1      12 Hamburg
2      2      -1 Hamburg
3      3       3 Hamburg
4      4      10 Hamburg
5      5      23 Hamburg
6      1      -9  Bremen
7      2      -1  Bremen
8      3       6  Bremen
9      4      10  Bremen
10     5      21  Bremen
```

Now your maximum temperature over all regions is simply `max(study$maxTemp)`.  No difficult indexing required.

---

If you really must insist on using your existing data structure, the equivalent command to get the maximum temperature is

```
max(sapply(study, function(x) max(x$region$maxTemp)))
```

Comment: What's with the downvote?  This better data structure makes it much easier to solve Sven's problem.

Comment: I agree, person down-voting should explain how this answer could be improved. Agreed, Richie's answer does not solve the problem OP's way, but it does provide a sensible alternative. As such it doesn't deserve (if that may be the case) a down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
> max(data.frame(study$results[[2]]$maxTemp, study$result[[1]]$maxTemp))
[1] 23
```

Let's analyze

```
> dput(data.frame(study$results[[2]]$maxTemp, study$result[[1]]$maxTemp))
structure(list(study.results..2...maxTemp = c(-9, -1, 6, 10, 
21), study.result..1...maxTemp = c(-12, -1, 3, 10, 23)), .Names = c("study.results..2...maxTemp", 
"study.result..1...maxTemp"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
#
# NOT ATOMIC VECTOR HERE, look you can find there maxTemp --> it will work!
```

comparing that to

```
>dput(study$results[[1:2]])
c(-12, -1, 3, 10, 23)              # ATOMIC VECTOR! Cannot use `$` here...
```

Now find the atomic vectors:

```
> Filter(is.atomic, study)
$region
[1] "Hamburg" "Bremen"
```

Also `"?Position(...)"`, you may like this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754475/rs-position-access-atomic-vectors-by-filteris-atomic-eq), addressing the title.